# Python list of defaultdict / tuples in CSV

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't find how to save a current list of dicts into CSV file.

Here is how data are formated :

```
{'8714789828558': ('5,51', 'A'), '3326100000182': ('15,00', "B"), '3286010016683': ('3,93', 'C'), (...) }
```

What I'm looking to have is like :
NUMBER, PRICE, LETTER
(...)

Here is my code :

```
with open('to_db.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="'")
writer.writerow(['ean', 'prices', 'desc'])
for row in minitems:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I tried several ways but have a result like this :

```
ean'prices'letter

8'7'1'4'7'8'9'8'2'8'5'5'8

3'3'2'6'1'0'0'0'0'0'1'8'2
```

Each ean number is separated with apostrophes, and there is no price or letter.

Thank you in advance if you see where is the mistake I'm not familiar with dicts.

Comment: When you iterate over a dictionary you iterate over the *keys*, so you should start from `for ean in minitems:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict.items` to iterate the key and value in the dict.

**Ex:**

```
with open('to_db.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="'")
    writer.writerow(['ean', 'prices', 'desc'])
    for k,v in minitems.items():
        writer.writerow([k] + list(v))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rakesh this is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want something like this.

```
minitems = {'8714789828558': ('5,51', 'A'), '3326100000182': ('15,00', "B")}

# list_of_rows = []
for x in minitems:
  row_list = []
  row_list.append(x)
  for y in minitems[x]:
    row_list.append(y)
  writer.writerow(row_list)
# list_of_rows.append(row_list)

# print(list_of_rows)
```